# How do I send rendered html AND data to the browser with node?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-development-server

In index.html I have a search form with action="/results". Server-side I have this code:

```
app.get('/results', function(req, res) {
  api.getInfo({query: req.query.searchStr}).then(function(data) {
    res.render('results', {title: 'Search Results'}, function(err, html) {
      res.send(html);
    });
  });
});
```

If I write `res.send(data)` then that data just gets turned into a string and spat out in the browser. So I need a way to send the rendered html, but also get `data` into the client-side javascript. What's the most conventional way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send the data to your template:

```
 res.render('results', {title: 'Search Results', data: data });
```

Then reference `data` in your template file:

```
// results.ejs
var data = <%= data %>;
// or
doSomethingWithData(<%= data %>);
```